# Automate clickonce builds

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce, configuration-files

I have a click-once application containing a database connection string.

My users have 8 different databases that they connect to using this program. The users might need to have several versions of the program open at once connected to different databases at once and I would like for them to have multiple “versions” of the same program installed at once. One for each database they connect to.

The only difference (for now) between the versions would be the connection string (stored in a .config file that would be easy to manipulate) and the name of the program (and thus the name of the shortcut in the start menu).

Is there a way of automating the creation of a clickonce install that would enable me to create a build-script that changes the .config file and the program name to do multiple versions at once?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think the simplest way is to clone your .vsproj and .config files n'th times.

In each cloned `.vsproj` you should specify desired program name, in each `.config` - desired connection string.

Then you should use [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) utility to build desired ClickOnce Applications from command line.

P.S. Why you don't want to modify your app code to embed multiple Database using functionality and switching between them?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly [automate publishing ClickOnce applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and set the ProductName (for the shortcut) and the AssemblyName (which I think needs to be different for each version)

How you then choose which connection string to use from the config file (assuming you have only one file) is a problem to be solved at runtime.